# how can i read this in php [{"profile":"Admin","Cpt_profile":"3"},{"profile":"Consultant","Cpt_profile":"1"}]

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, php-5.3

how can i read this

```
[{"profile":"Admin","Cpt_profile":"3"},  
 {"profile":"Consultant","Cpt_profile":"1"}]
```

in php please  i want to have ,

```
profile : admin 
cpt_profile : 3
```

and

```
profile :consultant 
cpt_profile :1
```

Comment: Looks like a JSON : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: it is a JSON String, use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert it into a PHP usable data type

Answer (score 2):

As already explained.

```
<?php

$json = json_decode('[{"profile":"Admin","Cpt_profile":"3"},{"profile":"Consultant","Cpt_profile":"1"}] ',true);

// print_r($json);
foreach($json as $j)
{
    print_r($j);
    print 'profile:'.$j['profile']."\r\n";
    print 'Cpt_profile:'.$j['Cpt_profile']."\r\n\r\n";
}

 ?>
```

To Call every Row use "foreach" as shown above

Comment: thanks for helping me, i did this and it works fine 
<?php $data = json_decode($series_data); ?>
<?php foreach ( $data as $key => $value){?>
<?php echo $value->profile.$value->Cpt_profile;  ?>
 <?php } ?>

Answer (score 0):

The string is JSON, simply use json_decode() to return an array, like so:

```
$json = '[{"profile":"Admin","Cpt_profile":"3"},{"profile":"Consultant","Cpt_profile":"1"}]';

$data = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($data);

// Will return
// Array
// (
//     [0] => Array
//         (
//             [profile] => Admin
//             [Cpt_profile] => 3
//         )

//     [1] => Array
//         (
//             [profile] => Consultant
//             [Cpt_profile] => 1
//         )

// )
```